# WPF Custom Buttons below ListBox Items

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

WPF Experts -

I am trying to add buttons below my custom listbox and also have the scroll bar go to the bottom of the control.  Only the items should move and not the buttons.  I was hoping for some guidance on the best way to achieve this.  I was thinking the ItemsPanelTemplate needed to be modified but was not certain.

Thanks

[image]

My code is below

```
   <!-- List Item Selected -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GotFocusStyle"  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.501"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF002F5C" Offset="0.5"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- List Item Hover -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverFocusStyle" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF013B73" Offset="0.501"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF014A8F" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF003363" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- List Item Selected -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LostFocusStyle" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF002F5C" Offset="0.4"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- List Item Highlight -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListItemHighlight" Color="#FFE38E27" />

    <!-- List Item UnHighlight -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListItemUnHighlight" Color="#FF6FB8FD" />

    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="ListItem_GotFocus"></EventSetter>
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="ListItem_LostFocus"></EventSetter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomListData" DataType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Margin="-2,0,0,-1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource ListItemUnHighlight}"
                        FontSize="24"
                        Tag="{Binding .}"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        MinHeight="55"
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
                        Background="{StaticResource LostFocusStyle}"
                        MouseMove="ListItem_MouseOver"
                        >
                    <Label.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Name="editMenu">
                            <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Label.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Margin="15,0,40,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                </Label>
                <Image 
                    Tag="{Binding .}"
                    Source="{Binding}"
                    Margin="260,0,0,0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Stretch="None"
                    Width="16"
                    Height="22" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:ImageLoader}"  MethodName="LoadImages"  />
</Window.DataContext>


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="320" Background="#FF021422" BorderBrush="#FF1C4B79" >

    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomListData }" />
        </Style>

    </ListBox.Resources>

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you place the two controls (the list and the buttons panel) into a StackPanel?

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="240">
    <ListBox Height="320"/>
    <Button Content="buttons go here"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You obviously won't get the listbox's scrollbar to go to the bottom of the screen, but you could fix that by putting in a ScrollBar control.

Editing templates might yield what you want but you may simply run into a point where items at the bottom of the list could be hidden by the button panel. You could overcome this obviously by increasing the bottom padding of the last item in that list or a similar margin/padding hack.

However, I don't think sizing the scrollbar to the bottom is the best idea in terms of common sense in user interfaces as scrollbars should conventionally be placed on the side of only what is scrollable.

Comment: I have talked with the rest of the team and I believe we are going to get new comps from our designer and do as you have suggested.  I think the scroll bar is confusing also.  I had one other question.  When I add a list item with a lot of text and it has to wrap multiple lines, I end up with a bunch of empty space at the bottom of the listbox.  Do you know how to trim off the extra space at the bottom ?

Comment: @Ryan: I just tried doing that (wrapped text in listbox) and saw what you mean. I'm not sure what causes that but there's no harm in writing it up as a new question so anyone else can help. Just link an image as well for instant clarity (I only got what you meant after having to replicate the scenario).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm joing the party rather late, but you should be able to accomplish this by applying a custom ScrollViewier control template to be used by the ListBox. I have not tested this, but it should work (or at least offer a starting point):

```
    <ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Items Go Here -->
                            <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />

                            <!-- Buttons Go Here -->        
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  >
                                  ...
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- ScrollBar spans all three rows but should only affect the presenter -->
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                        />

                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                        />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```